# SDL game : crash on 2D vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct, sdl

I am making a game using SDL and everything works fine but when I test it on Windows 7 (I code on win XP) it crashes on this part :

```
void ImageManager::DrawObjectTile(int i,int j)
{
           ScreenPosition.x = (j*TITLE_SIZE) - MapScrollX;
           ScreenPosition.y = (i*TITLE_SIZE) - MapScrollY;
           if (Main_BuildingManager_Ptr->Building_Vector[i][j].BuildingType==TX_EmptyTile)
           {
                Source.x = EMPTY_TILE_X;
                Source.y = EMPTY_TILE_Y;
                SDL_RenderCopy( Main_System_Ptr->GetRenderer(),
                Sheet_1,
                &Source,
                &ScreenPosition);
           }
```

Basicaly it crashes on this line :

```
 if (Main_BuildingManager_Ptr->Building_Vector[i][j].BuildingType==TX_EmptyTile)
```

I've been trying to debug this, i and j variables are allright. Also Vector is filled.

```
BuildingManager::BuildingManager()
{
    Building_Vector.resize(LEVEL_HEIGHT);

         for (int y=0; y<Building_Vector.size(); y++)
         {
             Building_Vector[y].resize(LEVEL_WIDTH);
                for (int x=0; x<Building_Vector[y].size(); x++)
                {
                       Building_Vector[y][x].BuildingType = TX_EmptyTile;
                }
         }
}
```

Edit: I've managed to go on win 7 with codeblocks installed and my code crashes but when I test it in debug mode it works perfectly.

Comment: What is `Main_BuildingManager_Ptr`? What is `Main_BuildingManager_Ptr->Building_Vector`? What is the values of the pointer? What are the values of `i` and `j` (and the values of `LEVEL_HEIGHT` and `LEVEL_WIDTH`)?

Comment: Also what exactly is the crash?

Comment: `Main_BuildingManager_Ptr` is a pointer to `Building_Manager` class. `Main_BuildingManager_Ptr->Building_Vector` is well, how I access the vector. `i` and `j` are both 0, `LEVEL_HEIGHT` is 58, and `LEVEL_WIDTH` is 64. The crash is simple famous "Dont Send" error.
What do you mean by value of the pointer ? The `Main_BuildingManager_Ptr` ?

Comment: I assume `Building_Vector` is a `std::vector<std::vector<something>>`? As for the pointer, yes how do you declare and *initialize* `Main_BuildingManager_Ptr`?

Comment: Yes, `Building_Vector` is `std::vector<std::vector<BuildingInfo>> Building_Vector` where `BuildingInfo` is a struct type array. As for a pointer, it's declared at top of my BuildingManager.cpp file `BuildingManager *Main_BuildingManager_Ptr` and I also have `extern BuildingManager *Main_BuildingManager_Ptr` in my BuildingManager.h file

Comment: And you do allocate memory that you make `Main_BuildingManager_Ptr` point to?

Comment: Im still pretty newbie with pointers, do you mean     `Main_BuildingManager_Ptr = new BuildingManager()` ? I have this in my main.cpp

Comment: Before the `DrawObjectTile` function is called? When you're in the debugger to examine the crash, it should be simple to check if the variable is `NULL` or not.

Comment: Yes, before the `DrawObjectTile` function is called, I checked the `Main_BuildingManager_Ptr` and it's not `NULL`. Also this code works perfectly on win XP but crashes on win 7.

Comment: Run your program under a debugger so you don't see the "Don't Send" prompt and get a better description of the crash.

Comment: If I use the Codeblocks built debugger all works well, no crash.